# Drone build status not updated in GitHub, pending forever

Tags: drone.io

I've seen the [Drone documentation](http://readme.drone.io/questions/how-to-install-behind-nginx/) for installing Drone behind a proxy and I've followed the directions exactly, but it's still not working for me. What's happening now is that GitHub successfully sends events to Drone, Drone does its builds just fine, but GitHub never receives a response when the build finishes. As a result, GitHub thinks that every build is "in progress" forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Drone does its builds just fine, but GitHub never receives a response
>   when the build finishes

When you install and configure the Drone server you need to set the `DRONE_HOST` environment variable [1]. This environment variable is used by Drone to determine its own public address so that it can post status updates to GitHub with the correct url.

```
DRONE_HOST=https://drone.yourcompnay.com
```

If this value is missing or is not properly configured Drone will fail to update the GitHub status, resulting in the following error logs:

```
level=error msg="error setting commit status for octocat/hello-world/244"
```

Please note that this issue is not related to nginx configuration.

[1] http://docs.drone.io/installation/

Comment: I see. I happened to update from Drone 0.5 (where a DRONE_HOST variable wasn't needed) to 0.7 the same day that I added the Nginx reverse proxy. That's my mistake for not narrowing down where the problem came in. Thanks!

Comment: For anybody seeing this in 2023+: there is no DRONE_HOST variable anymore. Variables DRONE_SERVER_HOST and DRONE_RPC_HOST can be set instead.